# Loop and merge in Qualtrics - Random & Equal Allocation?

Tags: html, loops, qualtrics

I have a survey on qualtrics currently where I need participants to rate three sound clips of a possible 48. Currently I have it as a loop and merge block, whereby one of the 48 possible sound clips is embedded for each participant - and this is repeated three times. 
Unfortunately, this means I have random but not necessarily equal allocation of rating of each clip.

I was thinking the easiest way to achieve this is by somehow coding the loop and merge so that once each clip has been rated 3 x it is removed from the loop and merge for all future participants. 
However, I have no idea how to do this.

Any suggestions would be wildly appreciated!!!

Comment: Is it correct to assume you have 48 items in your loop and merge and you are using the loop and merge options to randomize the loop and display only 1 of the loops?

Comment: Correct, except that I am randomising the loop to display 3 loops per participant

Answer (score 3):

In a block before your loop & merge block, create a hidden question with your 48 sound clips as answer options.  Then use Advanced Randomization to display a random subset of 3, and check the `Evenly Present Elements` box. Update your loop to loop based on the `Displayed Choices` in your hidden question. Uncheck the `randomize loop order` option in your loop & merge block.

Javascript for your hidden question can be found here (also copied below): https://gist.github.com/marketinview/d9c9f7f438c771850819

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
var questionDiv = this.getQuestionContainer();
questionDiv.style.display = "none";
this.clickNextButton();
});
```

Comment: Does this approach scale? If I have 2000 images to rate, does this work?

Comment: It should, but you'll have to try it.