# Setting up Loop & Merge in Qualtrics based on Displayed Choices in hidden question

Tags: loops, qualtrics

I have around 100 items from which I want each participant to rate a random subset of 5 with the same set  of questions, without getting messy data files with many blank cells at the end of the study.

This is my first time using `Loop & Merge` and I did manage to put in all my items using Field 1 and then the piped text etc., but I realised this cannot evenly present items, so I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957481/loop-and-merge-in-qualtrics-random-equal-allocation) solution about creating a hidden question first – but I don’t understand how/ where to update my loop to loop based on the `Displayed Choices` in my hidden question.

Other links and ChatGPT give replies based on the old interface so I am a little lost.

Could anyone please help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it in the Loop & Merge setup:
[image: Loop and Merge based on displayed choices in a previous question]

Comment: Thank you! When I clicked on 'Loop based off of a question' the first box showed up, containing 'select a question' but then nothing else, but I've come to realise my error was having the hidden prior question in the same block! Thank you very much for helping a numpty!